# Worksheet_change Log return value from same row as target but a specific column

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code I am using to track changes per sheet by cell returning different values at the time of the change.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim strAddress As String
Dim val
Dim dtmTime As Date
Dim Rw As Long

If Intersect(Target, Range("A:AZ")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   'change range to suit
dtmTime = Now()
With Target
      val = .Value
       strAddress = .Address
End With

Rw = Sheets("Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
With Sheets("Log")
    .Cells(Rw, 1) = strAddress
    .Cells(Rw, 2) = Me.Name 'Sheet Name
    .Cells(Rw, 3) = Environ("UserName")
    .Cells(Rw, 4) = dtmTime
    .Cells(Rw, 5) = val
    .Cells(Rw, 6) = ActiveWorkbook.FullNameURLEncoded 'Address of workbook at the time

End With
End Sub
```

Now I want to also track the value in the intersect of the Target Row and Column A at the time of the change, reason being is that the sheets are subject to filtering and rows being added, and knowing what the value of Column A was will identify where changes were made.

I.e. A change was made in cell B5, I need the value of A5. Z98, A98 and etc.

Comment: Do you mean something like `Target.Parent.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value`?

Comment: Or `Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value`.

Comment: It works so yes, thank you so much. BigBen's also works, y'all the best.

Comment: Both “Target.Parent.” and “Me.” in first two comments  can be omitted since inside a worksheet event handler the sheet itself is implicitly taken for any unqualified range reference